# ajax not getting servlet response 200 Ok

Tags: html, ajax, servlets

I have to make ajax call to servlet and update a part of page in html. here is my code.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function waitForStatus() {
              alert("link clicked");
              var xmlhttp;
              if (window.XMLHttpRequest)  {
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
              else {
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }


               xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                       alert("Received response text :::: "+ xmlhttp.responseText);
                       document.getElementById("response").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }
                };
                xmlhttp.open("GET","test",true);
                xmlhttp.send(null);
           return true;
        }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="TestWS.jnlp" onclick="waitForStatus()" >Download webstart & wait for status</a>
<p id="response"></p>
</body>
</html>

And my servlet is as follows:

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i ++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Slept :: "+ i);
        }
        System.out.println("Sending response now");
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        out.write("hello second servlet");
        out.close();

    }
```

I can see on server logs that servlet is sending 200OK. But the ajax onreadystatechange does not get xmlhttp.status == 200 and it is not updating my field. I get readyState  = 4 also. In firebug, it does not show that 200 OK was received. I have no clue what i am doing wrong. can anybody please help. This code works on IE perfectly. But on firefox, it does not work at all. I am loading the HTML from server. 
    `"http://localhost:8080/myproject/index.html"` and `"http://localhost:8080/myproject/test"` work perfectly fine on both IE and browser. Only if i call from ajax it is not working.

```
Regards,
Triveni
```

Comment: check xmlhttp object by putting in console.log

Comment: Add `console.log(xmlhttp.status)` before the if condition in `onreadystatechange ` callback

Comment: @ArunPJohny the status is always 0

Answer (score 1):

Hey just remove the href="TestWS.jnlp" with href="#" then try. It will send the response.

Comment: Ya. I tried that. And it works. But, I want two actions to be done on click of the link. One is to download the web start tool and another to wait for response from server. Since response might come little later, i want it to be ajax. Is it not possible to do it this way.

Comment: If you are trying to get both the things, write the code of TestWS.jnlp page to test page it will send response till the downloading is not completed.

Comment: while downloading you can check the status of the response using xmlhttp.readyState==3.

Comment: TestWS.jnlp is a web start file i want to download to user's system. It will check some status on user's system and post it to server. Meanwhile, my ajax request would have fired and it will be waiting for this staus from webstart tool to be received on the server. Once, the tool posts response, the server sends 200 OK and ajax onreadystatechange should be called. But its not workin this way